# What happens if you are unable to scry because your library is empty?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What happens to a player if they have to scry (for whatever reason), but are unable to scry a card because their library is empty? Does scrying an empty library trigger a loss?

Related to [What happens if you are unable to draw because your library is empty?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/24161/what-happens-if-you-are-unable-to-draw-because-your-library-is-empty)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You lose when you draw a card in an empty library due to rule 104.3c:

> If a player is required to draw more cards than are left in his or her library, he or she draws the remaining cards, and then loses the game the next time a player would receive priority. (This is a state-based action. See rule 704.)

Scrying doesn't cause you to draw cards. It only allows you to look at the top X cards of your library and put them on the top/bottom of your library. See rule 701.17a:

> To “scry N” means to **look** at the top N cards of your library, then put any number of them on the bottom of your library in any order and the rest on top of your library in any order.

*emphasis mine*

If scry made you draw it would say draw and not look.

source [1](https://tappedout.net/mtg-questions/does-scrying-an-empty-library-trigger-a-loss/) [2](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Scry)

Comment: Same answer with Surveil.

Comment: It might be a good idea to mention that a scry with an empty library does nothing, but an effect that tells you to scry and also do something else still does that something else.

Comment: And that anything that triggers off scrying will still trigger, even though your scry did nothing. (The same is true of shuffling a library with 1 or fewer cards in it.)